# How should the search autocomplete module be configured to recognise spaces?

Tags: search, ajax

We're using the [Search Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) module to power a site search for users. Unfortunately, it doesn't like spaces in the username. Has anyone faced this and found a simple solution?

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that spaces in usernames are even possible. Are they out of the box (if so, which version of Drupal you are using?), or what you did to get them working?

Comment: they're definitely possible out of the box in D7...